# Resizing partition in VMware Fusion didn't work

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-fusion, gparted

I migrated a Parallels VM to VMware Fusion.  That worked well, although the original partition size was way too small (8GB).  Following some instructions from VMware, I used the Fusion GUI to extend the size of the disk to 20GB, and then I booted from a GPartEd LiveCD to grow the C: partition to the full 20GB.

That seemed to work, and I can see that the disk is 20GB in Disk Manager, but it still thinks the actual partition is 8GB.  [Here is a screenshot of it](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46958/screenshots/NewDiskSpace.png).  What can I do to get the entire 20GB usable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved... please read [this thread](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=13793) from the GParted forum for details.